# How to smooth the corner joining the end point of a Bezier curve and the start point of an elliptical arc?

Tags: pstricks

The following figure shows the problem. The corners that are magnified should be smooth (not smooth defined in mathematics).

I have changed `liftpen` from `0` to `2`, but the problem still exists.

How to smooth the corners?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=15pt

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7,-5)(7,5)
    \psellipse[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.75,fillcolor=yellow](0,0)(7.0,4.3)
    \psellipse[linewidth=0.5,dimen=middle](0,0)(6.5,3.8)
    \def\left{
        \pscustom*[fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0.1]{
        \psline(0,2.7)(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
        \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
        \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(2,3.1)
        % How to smooth the corner between the previous path and the next path?
        \psellipticarcn(0,0)(6.0,3.3){!3.1 2 atan}{!-2.8 3.2 atan}
        \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
        \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
    }}\left
        \psscalebox{-1 1}{\left}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you looking for the optional argument `linejoin=1` ?

Comment: You have a problem with your path as Werner already pointed out. The end of `\psbezier` and the beginnung of `\psellipticarc` is connected by a line!

Comment: @Damian: I do not understand what you mean? `\psbezier` needs four points. Only in `\pscustom` the first one is the current point.

Comment: @Damin: sure, you can take the last point for calculating the start angle, but your last point of `\psbezier` is inside the elliptic arc, the reason why you _always_ have to connect the points.

Comment: @Damin: Again: that is _not_ the source of the problem. The source is your last point which is _inside_ the elliptic arc and not _on_ the arc.

Comment: `(2,3.1)` is not _on_ the elliptic arc. The reason why you _always_ have to draw a line from there to the start point of the arc. See Werners answer where he modified thes coordinates of this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Herbert's comment in many places, here is the solution:

Pass `correctAngle=false,dimen=middle` options to `\psellipticarcn` and make the last point of Bezier coincide with the first point of elliptic arc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=15pt


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7,-5)(7,5)
    \psellipse[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.75,fillcolor=yellow](0,0)(7.0,4.3)
    \psellipse[linewidth=0.5,dimen=middle](0,0)(6.5,3.8)
    \def\left{
        \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red,fillcolor=black]{
        \psline(0,2.7)(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
        \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
        \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(!76 cos 6 mul 76 sin 3.3 mul)
        \psellipticarcn[correctAngle=false,dimen=middle](0,0)(6.0,3.3){76}{-76}
        \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
        \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
    }}\left
        \psscalebox{-1 1}{\left}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to group lines and curves within a `\pscustom` command: all the pieces now form a unique line. For example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,2)

\psline[linecolor=red](0,0.5)(1,1.5)
\psline[linecolor=red](1,1.5)(0,1.5)

\pscustom{
    \psline(0,0)(1,1)
    \psline(1,1)(0,1)
}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: There is no need for `\pscustom`, `linejoin` does it already

Comment: @Herbert: Can you please include an example of `linejoin` that is not within `\pscustom`. My understanding of the documentation requires that setting to be specified for use in a `\pscustom` command. This can be done in two ways: in a `\code`command with the PostScript `setlinejoin` or by redefining some commands. Either way, the simplest approach is to just place things within a `\pscustom` command.

Comment: @Frédéric: there is a misunderstanding: I meant that in your example a `\psline(0,0)(1,1)(0,1)` would already use an internal setting of `linejoin`

Comment: @Damian: no reason to downvote it ...

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for your comment. I had kept the two line segments separate to show what `\pscustom` does.

Answer (score 1):

The clipping path of `\psellipticarc[n]` (I think) does not properly join with the former constructs. Otherwise, including `linejoin=1` as part of your `\pscustom` options (see section **L.8 Line connections**, p 304 of the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf)). Here I've just extended the `\psbezier` to line up with `\psellipticarcn` better, causing the illusion that it worked. Herbert will be able to find out what the actual problem is, I'm sure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-add
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% http://ctan.org/pkg/preview
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=15pt

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-7,-5)(7,5)
  \psellipse[fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.75,fillcolor=yellow](0,0)(7.0,4.3)
  \psellipse[linewidth=0.5,dimen=middle](0,0)(6.5,3.8)
  \def\left{%
    \pscustom*[fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0.1]{%
      \psline(0,2.7)(0.5,2.7)(1,3.25)
      \psbezier(1.2,1.3)(1.3,1.0)(2.0,1.0)
      \psbezier(3.0,1.0)(3.0,2.2)(2,3.1112)% Modified last coordinate from (2,3.1)
      \psellipticarcn(0,0)(6.0,3.3){!3.1 2 atan}{!-2.8 3.2 atan}
      \psbezier(4,-2)(4,0)(2.2,-1.8)
      \psbezier(1.5,-1)(1,-1)(0,-3.2)
    }%
  }%
  \left
  \psscalebox{-1 1}{\left}% right
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```